# Having trouble with includes and relative paths

Tags: php, include, relative-path

I'm building out a very small page that will live for the duration of a 5 day conference. Each day the site needs to load new content so I'm using a small script to load in an include file. I'm trying to get my includes to be relative paths but something isn't working right. Below is the current code I'm working with that uses an array (24 is for today's date so I could check to see if ti was working) for the dates that maps to a file and a default piece of content should the conditional not return with a result.

```
        <?php

        $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

        $date = date("j");
        $event_dates = array(24,15,16,17,18,19);

        if (in_array($date, $event_dates)) {
            $path .= "/_includes/date-".$date.".php";
            include($path);
        }
        else {
            $path .= "/_includes/default.php";
            include($path);
        }

    ?>
```

If I include "_includes/default.php", everything works fine and this just might need to be the solution for now but I'd like to figure out the relative path problem all the same in case I run into this same issue at a later date. Also, if I change the include to an echo then I get the result I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `.=`, the `"/_includes/..."` string is concatenated to `$path`. It will then have something of the form `localhost/_includes/...`. This does not contain the scheme (HTTP(S)), so this will only work if you actually have a folder `localhost` in that directory.

If you want the current directory, you could use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead. You could also use `./_includes/...` as path if `_includes` is a subdirectory of the current directory, etc.

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` and cleaning up my concatenated $path variables to remove the leading "/" worked fine. I had tried `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT];` but when that went to a live server instead of my local MAMP development environment I got a stream error. Too bad includes are so finicky to get to play nice with multiple environments easily but I think this is the solution moving forward.